# SQL Server 2012 Use of EXCEPT with ORDER BY

Tags: sql-server

I can execute this.

```
SELECT TOP 10 model, price
FROM PC 
EXCEPT
SELECT TOP 9 model, price
FROM PC ORDER BY price DESC
```

But when I run this, I got syntax error near 'Order'.

```
SELECT TOP 10 model, price
FROM PC ORDER BY price DESC
EXCEPT
SELECT TOP 9 model, price
FROM PC ORDER BY price DESC
```

And I have to do this instead. Why doesn't the above work?

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT TOP 10 model, price
FROM PC ORDER BY price DESC
EXCEPT
SELECT TOP 9 model, price
FROM PC ORDER BY price DESC
) X
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Explanation**

The `ORDER BY` clause is allowed in two situations: when a `TOP` (or `OFFSET/FETCH`) exists, and in the outermost query of a series of queries/subqueries that function together as a single query. Now, you cannot use `ORDER BY` in an inner query context without the `TOP` clause, as you know. But additionally, when the two situations (`TOP` vs. outermost) are in conflict, the outermost query context takes precedence.

When using `UNION`, `EXCEPT`, and `INTERSECT`, the outermost query context, where `ORDER BY` is expected, is the *last* query, though it applies to the entire query. Attempting to make an individual subquery ordered that is connected to others with one of these keywords is not permitted because of the outermost query context rules taking precedence.

By moving the outermost query context out of the `EXCEPT`ed queries through the use of the derived table, as you have done, the individual subqueries are now allowed to have their own individual `ORDER BY` clauses.

**A possible improvement**

If you are using SQL Server 2012 or higher, it's better to just use the `OFFSET` and `FETCH` keywords to achieve your goal:

```
SELECT model, price
FROM dbo.PC
ORDER BY price DESC
OFFSET 9 ROWS 
FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

This way the query expresses your intent more clearly, you don't have to duplicate the query, and these together are a big win for future maintenance and the understanding of any future developer looking at the query. Remember that our code should be, in order:

1. Correct (and any performance that's part of the definition of correct)
2. Clear
3. Concise
4. Fast

Here, clarity would seem to demand using the correct query keywords instead of achieving the same result through somewhat hacky (though clever) means.

Comment: Thanks ErikE. Where in the SQL Server literature does it mention the TOP/ORDER BY precedence? And you forgot to include `ORDER BY` in the code with `OFFSET-FETCH`.

Comment: I'm not aware of any place in the literature that mentions this precedence. My statements are made based on an analysis of the behavior of the query parser.